# Find next element with a class is exist

Tags: jquery

In JQuery if we need to find a element exist we can use

```
 $(".pane").length
```

In my case i need to append a div like this

```
parent('.parent').next().append('<div class="classname">....</div>');
```

But before append i need to check already that div element exist next to my parent.
I wrote like this. but it is not checking

```
function show(xxx)
{
  if(!($(xxx).parent('.parent').next('.classname').length))
  {

  }
}
```

But not working. help to write the if check

Comment: can you share your html sample

Comment: what was the answer... first part or second one of my answer

Comment: i checked with first one only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the `classname` is not the next sibling, it is the content of the next sibling

```
function show(xxx) {
    if (!($(xxx).parent('.parent').next().find('.classname').length)) {
        $(xxx).parent('.parent').next().append('<div class="classname">....</div>');
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C99xa/)

---

Or do you want something like

```
function show(xxx) {
    var $p = $(xxx).parent('.parent');
    if (!$p.next().is('.classname')) {
        $p.after('<div class="classname">....</div>');
    }
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C99xa/5/)

Comment: it's working fine. you are right sir, sibling cann't be used because my structure repeats

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
$(obj).parent('.parent').next().find('.classname').length
```

Answer (score 0):

use like

```
if(!($(xxx).parent('.parent').find('.classname').length))
```

Answer (score -1):

try this ,

```
if(!$(xxx).parent('.parent').next().hasClass('classname'))
  {
     $(xxx).parent('.parent').after('<div class="classname">....</div>');
  }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/5j9zC/23/)